# 2 Android devices blocking each others HTTP requests in same LAN

Tags: android, http, routes

I have an Android app which is continuously downloading JSON files with status updates, and if needed it downloads corresponding zip files. What the application exactly does is irrelevant.

The problem is that if i have 2 devices running in the same LAN with the app installed, one app blocks HTTP request of the other one. So one app is running fine, the other one is constantly running into timeouts for exactly the same request (only the token in the GET parameter differs).

When i turn of the "working" device, the block is released - and the other device is running fine, without timeouts.

Myself i think it is an routing issue.
Does anybody know how to prevent this?

In my app i connect through Volley. I am using a singleton for the connection pool - build by the documentation you can find on https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html

Comment: The devices are rooted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with android devices and timestamps that are used for the connection. I found the solution to the problem.

Search the solution in the TCP protocol / settings.

Answer (score 0):

This is not likely a client issue (your Android app). You should check your server implementation first.

Singleton or transient RequestQueue in Android app doesn't matter. Because number of concurrent GET requests to server depends on number of devices you have.

Comment: What do you think that could be wrong in the server implementation? I already checked it before, so i do not know where to look for.

Comment: If you can't share your server code here, I would suggest you to take a look around all statements related to downloading file on server to see if there is any exclusive lock (synchronized lock) blocking those statements or not.